# Hive Summing up data in the table based on the date range

Tags: sql, date, datetime, hive, hql

Have a table with the following schema design and the data residing inside it is like:

```
ID HITS MISS DDATE
1 10    3    20180101
1 33    21   20180122
1 84    11   20180901
1 11    2    20180405
1 54    23   20190203
1 33    43   20190102
4 54    22   20170305
4 56    88   20180115
5 87    22   20180809
5 66    48   20180617
5 91    53   20170606
```

`DataTypes:`

```
ID    INT
HITS  INT 
MISS  INT
DDATE STRING
```

The requirement is to calculate the total of the given (`HITS` and `MISS`) on yearly basis i.e `2017`,`2018`,`2019`...

Written the following query:

```
SELECT ID,
SUM(HITS) AS HITS,SUM(MISS) AS MISS,
CASE 
    WHEN DDATE BETWEEN '201701' AND '201712' THEN '2017' ELSE 
    'NOTHING' END AS TTL_YR17_DATA
CASE 
    WHEN DDATE BETWEEN '201801' AND '201812' THEN '2018' ELSE 
    'NOTHING' END AS TTL_YR18_DATA
CASE 
    WHEN DDATE BETWEEN '201901' AND '201912' THEN '2019' ELSE 
    'NOTHING' END AS TTL_YR19_DATA
FROM 
     HST_TABLE
WHERE 
     DDATE BETWEEN '201801' AND '201812'
GROUP BY 
     ID,DDATE;
```

But, the query is not fetching the expected result.

`Actual O/P:`

```
1 10   3    2018
1 33   21   2018
1 84   11   2018
1 11   2    2018
1 54   23   2019
1 33   43   2019
4 54   22   2017
4 56   88   2018
5 87   22   2018
5 66   48   2018
5 91   53   2017
```

`Expected O/P:`

```
1   138 37  2018
4   56  88  2018
5   153 70  2018
1   87  66  2019
5   91  53  2017
```

`Another related question:`

Is there a way that I can avoid passing the *DDATE* range in the query? As this should be given by the user and shouldn't be hardcoded.

Any help/advice to achieve the above two requirements will be really helpful.

Comment: What is the data type of DDATE?

Comment: @forpas I've updated my question with the datatypes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK,it's easy to implement this with the `substring` function in HIVE, as below:

```
select
    substring(dddate,0,4) as the_year,
    id,
    sum(hits) as hits_num,
    sum(miss) as miss_num
from
    hst_table
group by
    substring(dddate,0,4),
    id
order by
    the_year,
    id
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer above by @Shawn.X is correct but has a logical flaw. Below is the corrected one:

```
select
    substring(ddate,0,4) as the_year,
    id,
    sum(hits) as hits_num,
    sum(miss) as miss_num
from
    hst_table
group by
    substring(ddate,0,4),
    id
order by
    the_year,
    id;
```